# Deploy multi modules Play project

Tags: java, scala, jpa, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to deploy a **Multi-Module** Play project using **SBT**.
Our project have 5 modules `[commons, channel , ...]`.
When I use `sbt run` in my local system every thing works fine.
For deploying in server I use `sbt dist` to [build the project](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Deploying#using-the-dist-task).
But when I run my application using script that is generated by `sbt dist`, the problems appears!

Here is one example of errors :

```
[error] error_handler - Unhandled Error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [automaticChannel.getTagByChannelId]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.buildQueryFromName(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:770)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createNamedQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at repositories.GenericRepository.namedQuery(GenericRepository.java:291)
    at repositories.GenericRepository.namedNativeQuery(GenericRepository.java:573)
    at repositories.AutomaticChannelRepository.getTagIds(AutomaticChannelRepository.java:63)
    at services.AutomaticChannelService.lambda$tagIds$6(AutomaticChannelService.java:159)
    at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.lambda$withTransaction$3(DefaultJPAApi.java:197)
    at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:138)
    at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:196)
```

The **GenericRepository** class exist in **commons** module and the **AutomaticChannelRepository** exist in **channel** module.

Part of `buid.sbt` file :

```
lazy val connector = (project in file("modules/connector"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    libraryDependencies += "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.4"
  )

lazy val common = (project in file("modules/common"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava)
  .dependsOn(connector)
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      javaJdbc,
      filters,
      guice,
      javaWs,
      ehcache,
      javaJpa,
      evolutions,
      "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "5.2.11.Final",
      "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-ehcache" % "5.2.11.Final",
      "org.hibernate.javax.persistence" % "hibernate-jpa-2.1-api" % "1.0.0.Final",
      "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.1",
      "com.oracle" % "ojdbc8" % "12.2.0.1",
      "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4",
      "commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6",
      "org.apache.commons" % "commons-collections4" % "4.1",
      "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-core" % "5.2.10.Final",
      "org.apache.tika" % "tika-core" % "1.13",
      "org.apache.tika" % "tika-parsers" % "1.13" exclude("com.google.code.gson", "gson"),
      "org.apache.tika" % "tika-xmp" % "1.13",
      "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.10.1",
      "com.thoughtworks.xstream" % "xstream" % "1.3"
    )
  )

lazy val search = (project in file("modules/search")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).dependsOn(common).settings(commonSettings)
lazy val channel = (project in file("modules/channel")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).dependsOn(common, search).settings(commonSettings)
lazy val recommend = (project in file("modules/recommend")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).dependsOn(common, search).settings(commonSettings)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava)
  .dependsOn(channel, recommend)
  .aggregate(channel, recommend)
  .settings(commonSettings)
```

I wonder what is the difference between `sbt run` and `sbt dist` ?

And what is the common and recommended way to deploy Multi-Module SBT projects?

Answer (score 0):

It's a classpath problem. You have to put the following code in your build.sbt:

```
PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false
```

By default resources from the project are not packaged in the jar file created by `sbt dist`.